# Pairs of consecutive values assigned to objects of different state.

Tags: probability

Seven objects of state A and eight objects of state B are assigned values across a variant range of 15. What is the expected number of pairs of such consecutive values that are assigned to objects of opposite state?

Comment: What is the probability that numbers 1 & 2 are assigned to persons of opposite sex? Same question for 2 & 3? For 3 & 4? Etc. Add.

Comment: What problems do you run into when looking at the probability that two people of opposite sex are next to each other? Isn't the probability that Adam and Betty get consecutive numbers just $14/\binom{15}2$? There are $\binom{15}2$ equally likely pair of numbers, and $14$ pairs of consecutive numbers, right?

Comment: One of the interesting things is that $E(X_1+\dots+X_{14})=E(X_1)+E(X_2)\dots+E(X_{14})$, even when the variables $X_1,\dots,X_{14}$ are not independent. So if $X_i$ is $0$ if $i,i+1$ have the same sex, and $1$ if $i,i+1$ have different sexes...

Comment: Yes, you just continue summing like that. But since the summands are all the same, the sum of those $14$ probabilities is just $14$ times the one you worked out. For each $j$ in $\{1,2,\dots,14\}$, the probability that $j$ and $j+1$ are assigned to persons of opposite sex is $8\cdot7/\binom{15}2=8/15$, so the expected value is $14\cdot8/15=112/15$.

Comment: With all due respect, you only think you understand linearity :) It is an amazingly powerful tool for computing expectations in ways that seem counter-intuitive. @Andover

Comment: Did I say utter lack? There are no future events. All the events happen at once. @Andover

Comment: No reason to believe that, @Andover. You could pick a random number from $1$ to $15!$ and look that up in a giant book which assigns the people. Thinking in terms of time is useless for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment, you correctly calculated the chance that $1$ and $2$ were assigned to opposite genders as $\frac{8}{15} * \frac{7}{14} + \frac{7}{15} * \frac{8}{14}$.  Nowhere in your calculation did you use anything about positions $1$ and $2$, so that is also the probability that positions $2$ and $3$ are opposite genders, or positions ... As there are $14$ pairs of positions next to each other, the expected number of pairs assigned to opposite genders is $14(\frac{8}{15} * \frac{7}{14} + \frac{7}{15} * \frac{8}{14})=\frac{112}{15}$

Comment: No. Again, the expectation doesn't care about whether the random numbers are independent. $E(X_1+X_2)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)$ whether they are independent or not. @Andover

Comment: @Andover What's this about "future" positions? I didn't see anything in the question about what order the labels were assigned; I assumed they were assigned simultaneously.

Comment: The linearity of expectation comes to your rescue.  We are calculating the probability for 3 and 4 ignoring (or averaging over) what happened at 1 and 2.

Comment: @Andover Linearity of expectation is just common sense. If I own a restaurant where I'm selling food and drink, then my average total sales = average food sales + average drink sales, regardless of how sales of food and drink may depend on each other. (In probability theory the average value is usually called the "expected value" or "mathematical expectation"; maybe the jargon is confusing.)